# jbpm timers are not running in two processes working simultaneously

Tags: timer, jbpm

I have two JBPM processes. They are almost the same.
In every process I create a loop with a timer (intermediate catch event).
When I start first or second process, everything works fine: the timer fires every loop (for example, duration is 1 second (PT1S) or 200ms).

**bpmn with timer in cycle**

[image: bpmn with timer in cycle]

**properties (timer)**

[image: properties (timer)]

But I've got a problem with timers, when I use two processes simultaneously. The timer works only in the process, which was started first, but never in the second process. Timers don't want to work simultaneously in two processes!

What's the matter? It looks like timers interfere each other in two processes.
Did somebody experience the problem?

I use JBPM 7.

Comment: Timer dont work in second process means, process execution didnt wait at timer node?  am I correct ? Ideally this should not happen.

Comment: it means, that the process stops in a timer.